# Не работает Elementor

Tags: wordpress

Не отображается последние блоки элементора,т.е. не применяются стили,в остальном сайт работает хорошо,в чем проблема? [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в консоли -> Elementor->Tools -> вкладка General -> Regenerate CSS и Sync Library  нажать. Это обновит стили и синхронизируются  библиотеки.

Answer (score -1):

Не работать может по нескольким причинам:
Недостаточно памяти - смотрим в настройках элементора

Меняли домен - надо обновить в настройках элементора - ввести старый и новый

**Если используете плагин WP security - в настройках файрволл вторая вкладка ДОП ПРАВИЛА ФАЙРВОЛЛА отключите четвёртую галочку
Запретить вредоносные строки в запросах:  защита от XSS-атак.**